# Filter the data by passing % in the where query of postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql

I have requirement to search the data based on the input given in the search box. 
To handle this I wrote query like

```
SELECT distinct d.desktop_id as desktopId,
                d.name as desktopName
from desktoptable
where d.name
ilike '%'+searchString+'%'
```

searchString : is nothing both the input i am passing to the query. This query is working fine all other input string except % and _ , I read in the postgres docs that "_ and % as wildcard characters denoting any single character and any string, respectively".

Is that mean I can pass % or _ as input to the query to filter the data. In my db there some records which have % and _ as well.

Can anyone let me know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your global `ILIKE` search isn't concatenating the way thought in the actual SQL query being run on Postgres.  For this reason, and also to avoid things like SQL injection, you should be using prepared statements in Java.  Something like this should work:

```
String query = "SELECT distinct d.desktop_id as desktopId, d.name as desktopName ";
       query += "from desktoptable where d.name ilike ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(1, "%" + handle(searchString) + "%");
```

Here `handle()` is a method which will especially escape wildcards and underscores for use in the `LIKE` operator.  AFAIK prepared statements will *not* automatically do this.

```
public String handle (String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("%", "\\%")
                .replaceAll("_", "\\_");
}
```

I tested this on Postgres, and a single backslash seems sufficient for escaping the `LIKE` special characters.

Comment: Your suggestions is right but plus OP want to escape % _ in search string I think.

Comment: @YeWin I don't think so, not from what I see.  It appears that he wants to do a wildcard search, in which case the `%` should _not_ be escaped in any way.

Comment: So if he put parameters like % _ in query your query will be " ILIKE %aa%_%. Because he want to pass % or _ as input to the query to filter the data

Comment: @YeWin I see your point now.  I think we need to manually escape wildcards and underscores in this case.

Comment: Sorry if there is any confusion, I have few records in db which are have special characters like %, _, $ etc. My requirement is to get all the desktops which have the special character % or _ in name. I hope this makes the question little clear